# What is meant by "trivial Taylor expansion" at one point?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> When analyzing  elliptic regularity in the neighborhood of a conical point on the boundary of an otherwise smooth domain, one is faced with a dilemma:  Near the singular point, the conical geometry suggests the use of estimates in weighted Soboloev spaces with homogeneous norms, and a well-known tool for analyzing them and for obtaining the estimates is the Mellin transform. This analysis is carried out in the classical paper [3] by Kondrat'ev.
> On the other hand, since this analysis corresponds to a blow-up of the corner, this is a diffeomorphism between the tangent cone and an infinite cylinder, the conical point moves to infinity, and **therefore functions in this class of spaces always have trivial Taylor expansion at the corner**. Depending on the weight index, they either habe no controlled behavior at the corner at all or they tend to zero.

What is meant by "trivial Taylor expansion" at one point?

If my function is $f(t)$. $f$ has trivial Taylor expansion in $a$  means that the series is equal to $0$ or it is equal to $f(a)$.
Please, can somebody tell me what is meant ? Thank you

I was reading, but is no clear

Comment: Please provide the context, otherwise we are unable to provide a relevant answer. We describe something as *trivial* in math if it is so elementary that it requires no derivation or computation, or if it has no substance or complexity. A trivial Taylor series is any that can be described as such, in a particular context (whether the function is the zero function, a constant function, or some such).

Comment: Thank you @Jam . I edited my question, i put some picture where it come from, thank you again

Comment: From reading the text, I would have expected the question to be about other concepts than Taylor expansions :D ... Regarding your question: Maybe trivial here means what is specified in the last sentence in the source.

Comment: I am still confuse, it is no clear in the source. thank you @klirk